# Django: How to use custom url name instead of 'password_reset_done' for password reset route in urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I am creating my first Django project and implementing password-reset functionality.
So I know that I have to configure the URLs with the following name and use inbuilt views.

1. password_reset
2. password_reset_done
3. password_reset_confirm
4. password_reset_complete

But I have created a seaparate application `accounts` to handle the authentication part
 and I am following a convention of prepending application name for naming application-specific URLs.
So all the URLs in the `accounts` app have `accounts-` prepended to them.

```
path('signup/', views.signup, name='accounts-signup'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='accounts-logout'),
```

---

**PROBLEM:**
But while creating password reset URLs, I have to use predefined names as mentioned above.
**Is there a way to use a custom name in place of these predefined names, or any way to override these in settings.py**

I checked [docs for settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/) but could not find anything.

**EXPECTATION:**
I want to be able to assign custom names like  `accounts-password_reset` and `accounts-password_reset_done`.

The app works fine with predefined names, but what If I want to create another app in the same project with a separate authentication system and separate routes.  Wouldn't the same name for reset password route can cause namespace collisions in other apps?

Comment: As a comment to your question about two apps having the same URL, django has a namespace method to resolve this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces. So in your accounts url file you could just have signup. Then in your html template you would used the name space like { % url "accounts:signup" }

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks for the quick reply! since `password_reset_done` is a special name, will it still work fine with namespaces?

Comment: I guess the question is are you planning to use django backend admin to do the password reset for you? or have you written your own view to handle it?

Comment: I am not sure. I am using `PasswordResetView` from `django.contrib.auth.views` and passing a kwarg `template_name`. I guess this is a custom view since I am just using the `form` provided by the `PasswordResetView`, and not using any custom password reset logic.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to append the `app` name to your `url` name, if you are working out of the `app` django namespaces let you specify wich `url` are you looking for.
Example:

```
reverse('accounts:password_reset')
```

This returns the view that handles the password reset that you specify in your `urls.py` file with `path('reset',ViewFunc,name='password_reset')`.